# javascript object: variable global can not read in different function

Tags: javascript, variables, object, styles, undefined

I have this script

```js
var b = {
  c: {
    a: document.querySelector(".a"),
    init: function() {
      this.a.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      this.a.addEventListener("click", b.c.change);
    },
    change: function() {
      this.a.style.width = "100px";
    }
  }
}
b.c.init();
```

```css
.a {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Why this.a style "undefine"???

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the change event handler, `this` refers to the dom element. So just change `this.a.style....` to `this.style....` .

```js
var b = {
  c: {
    a: document.querySelector(".a"),
    init: function(){
      this.a.style.backgroundColor="red";
      this.a.addEventListener("click", b.c.change);
    },
    change: function(){
      this.style.width="100px";
    }
  }
}
b.c.init();
```

```css
.a {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Comment: but as selecting with class if having multiple elements will create problem.. so better go with "id".

Comment: @BEJGAMSHIVAPRASAD  what do you mean?

Comment: @BEJGAMSHIVAPRASAD In this special setup `a` will always contain only **one** element because `document.querySelector()` only returns the first matched element.

Comment: thanks @Pranav C Balan

Comment: @FerryAlfanso :glad to help

Answer (score 1):

First, in change event, `this`  is pointing to `DOM` element and not object. So you can directly update style using `this`.

Second, inside `a`, `this` will point to `c`, so instead of `b.c.change`, you can directly do `this.change`

```js
var b = {
  c: {
    a: document.querySelectorAll(".a"),
    init: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.a.length; i++) {
        this.a[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        this.a[i].addEventListener("click", this.change);
      }
    },
    change: function() {
      console.log(this.innerHTML)
      this.style.width = "100px";
    }
  }
}
b.c.init();
```

```css
.a {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">1</div>
<div class="a">2</div>
<div class="a">3</div>
<div class="a">4</div>
<div class="a">5</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Rajesh, How about if we have more dom element in "change" function?

Comment: @FerryAlfanso you will have to loop over them and assign handler to every element. Please check the updated answer

Comment: Hi @Rajesh, i add new div.b and force to expand in change function. am i right? or any sugestion? thanks

Comment: @FerryAlfanso you can update the selector and it should work

Answer (score -4):

Try once this will work..

```js
var b = {
  c: {
    a: document.getElementById("a"),
    init: function(){
      this.a.style.backgroundColor="red";
      this.a.addEventListener("click", b.c.change);
    },
    change: function(){
      this.style.width="100px";
    }
  }
}
b.c.init();
```

```css
#a {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
```

Comment: :D thaaaaaaankkkkkkkkkssss........

Comment: Here `self` is a pointing to `window` and only reason this is working is because you have used `id` as `a`

Comment: @Rajesh  The only reason this is working, is because he has created a global variable call `a`.

Comment: @Keith The global property `a` is created by the browser -> [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

Comment: ups sorry @BEJGAM SHIVA PRASAD, im too excited, self not working and i have problem with more dome in change function

Comment: @FerryAlfanso: I just modified check once..

Comment: @Andreas  Indeed, my bad. I was thinking he's doing `self.a =`, but it's the `<div id="a">` creating it.